# Gdx.files.local and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in android

Tags: android, libgdx, android-permissions

I developed my LibGdx based Android game, I use the below code which has `Gdx.files.local`. Does it need a `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in android ?

```
private FileHandle getFontFile(String filename, int fontSize) { 
    return Gdx.files.local(generatedFontDir + fontSize + "_" + filename); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local File Storage of LibGDX is the same as [Internal storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) on Android. You can read and write to this storage but it is private storage of your application so only your App can access it.

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local(String path);
```

> No permissions are required if you want to read and write on internal storage of
>   Android.

Here is the test code

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("prueba.txt");
file.writeString("HELLO WORLD", false);            //write to file
System.out.println(charString=file.readString());   //read file
```

I've tested on Android Marshmallow and on Kitkat OS devices and my target and compile sdk version is 25.

For more details take a look on libgdx [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#file-storage-types).